# Custom buffer for FFMPEG

Tags: c++, windows, video, ffmpeg, buffer

I have a question regarding buffer read with ffmpeg. 
Idea is as it follows: an outside module (can not change it) is providing me video stream in chunks of data and it is giving me input data and it's size in bytes ("framfunction" function input parameters). I have to copy input data to a buffer and read it with ffmpeg (Zeranoe) and extract video frames. Each time I receive new data, my function "framfunction" will be called. All unprocessed data from a first run will be moved at the beginning of the buffer followed by a new data on the second run and so on. It is essentially based on [source](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html) and Dranger tutorials. My current attempt is like this and just look at comments (I've left only ones regarding current buffer function) in code to get a picture what I want to do(I know it is messy and it works - sort of; skipping some frames. Any suggestions around ffmpeg code and buffer design are welcome):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavformat/avio.h>
#include <libavutil/file.h>
}
struct buffer_data {
   uint8_t *ptr;
   size_t size;
};

static int read_packet(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)
{
   struct buffer_data *bd = (struct buffer_data *)opaque;
   buf_size = FFMIN(buf_size, bd->size);
   memcpy(buf, bd->ptr, buf_size);
   bd->ptr += buf_size;
   bd->size -= buf_size;
   return buf_size;
}

class videoclass
{
private:
   uint8_t* inputdatabuffer;
   size_t offset;

public:
   videoclass();
   ~videoclass();
   int framfunction(uint8_t* inputbytes, int inputbytessize);
};

videoclass::videoclass()
   : inputdatabuffer(nullptr)
   , offset(0)
{
   inputdatabuffer = new uint8_t[8388608]; //buffer where the input data will be stored
}

videoclass::~videoclass()
{
   delete[] inputdatabuffer;
}


int videoclass::framfunction(uint8_t* inputbytes, int inputbytessize)
{
   int i, videoStream, numBytes, frameFinished;
   AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
   AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = NULL;
   AVIOContext   *avio_ctx = NULL;
   AVCodec   *pCodec = NULL;
   AVFrame   *pFrame = NULL;
   AVFrame   *pFrameRGB = NULL;
   AVPacket packet;
   uint8_t   *buffer = NULL;
   uint8_t   *avio_ctx_buffer = NULL;
   size_t   avio_ctx_buffer_size = 4096;
   size_t   bytes_processed = 0;
   struct buffer_data bd = { 0 };

   //if (av_file_map("sample.ts", &inputbytes, &inputbytessize, 0, NULL) < 0)//
   //   return -1;

   memcpy(inputdatabuffer + offset, inputbytes, inputbytessize);//copy new data to buffer inputdatabuffer with offset calculated at the end of previous function run. In other words - cope new data after unprocessed data from a previous call 
   offset += inputbytessize; //total number of bytes in buffer. Size of an unprocessed data from the last run + size of new data (inputbytessize)

   bd.ptr = inputdatabuffer;
   bd.size = offset;

   if (!(pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context()))
      return -1;
   avio_ctx_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(avio_ctx_buffer_size);
   avio_ctx = avio_alloc_context(avio_ctx_buffer, avio_ctx_buffer_size,0, &bd, &read_packet, NULL, NULL);
   pFormatCtx->pb = avio_ctx;

   av_register_all(); 
   avcodec_register_all();

   pFrame = av_frame_alloc(); 
   pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc(); 

   if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, NULL, NULL, NULL) != 0) 
      return -2;
   if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
      return -3;

   videoStream = -1;
   for (i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
      if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) { 
         videoStream = i;
         break;
      }
   if (videoStream == -1) 
      return -4;

   pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec; 

   pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id); 
   if (pCodec == NULL){
      std::cout << "Unsupported codec" << std::endl;
      return -5;
   }

   if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
      return -6; 

   numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height); 
   buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

   avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_BGR24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height); 

   while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0){
      if (packet.stream_index == videoStream){ 
         avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet); 
         if (frameFinished){ 
            std::cout << "Yaay, frame found" << std::endl;
            }

      }
      av_free_packet(&packet); 

      bytes_processed = (size_t)pFormatCtx->pb->pos; //data which is processed so far (x bytes out of inputbytessize)??????????????????????????????
   }

   offset -= bytes_processed; //size of unprocessed data

   av_free(buffer);
   av_free(pFrameRGB);
   av_free(pFrame);

   avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

   av_freep(&avio_ctx->buffer);
   av_freep(&avio_ctx);


   avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);


   memmove(inputdatabuffer, inputdatabuffer + bytes_processed, offset);//move unprocessed data to begining of the main buffer

      return 0;
}
```

Call of my function would be something like this

```
WHILE(VIDEO_INPUT)
{
    READ VIDEO DATA FROM INPUT BUFFER
    STORE DATA FROM INPUT BUFFER AND SIZE OP THAT DATA TO VARIABLES NEW_DATA AND NEW_DATA_SIZE
    CALL FUNCTION FRAMMUNCTION AND PASS NEW_DATA AND NEW_DATA_FUNCTION
    DO OTHER THINGS
}
```

What I would like to know is what is exact size of unprocessed data. Comments in code are showing my attempt but I think it is not good enough so I need some help with that issue.

EDIT: magic question is how to get correct "bytes_processed" size. I've also made an pdf with explanation how my buffer should work [pdf file](http://www.filedropper.com/buffer)
Thanks